# CSS - background color around image with some transparent pixels

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have a fixed size image and part of it is transparent, which I currently use as a DIV background. I must place the **image precisely in the screen center**.

The problem is that I need the all space **around** the image to be black. If I set it with `background: black url(...` - image's transparent pixels also become black, which is wrong.

Another problem is that the website content is dynamic, so I can't cheat with 2 DIVs with the same background image and different filters. I need to look **through** transparent pixels clearly.

My current code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .image {
            height: 100%;
            background: black url(image.png) center center no-repeat;
            background-size: auto 100%;
        }   
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In short - I need to look at the content through the transparent part of the image, the other part of the screen must be black. How do I achieve this?

Comment: why not add background to the html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest an **enormous** box-shadow;

```css
body {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: url(https://www199.lunapic.com/editor/premade/transparent.gif);
  background-size: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: maybe max-height/max-width instead ;)

Comment: You would recommend it because of simplicity, some performance differences or something else?

Comment: @Alexey I meant that instead fixed width/height we can consider max-width/max-width to have it responsive for bigger image

Comment: Max-width would not apply to a **background-image** as is, apparently, the case here.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact dimension of your image you can use `linear-gradient`  where you can speficy a size so they cover partially the background.

Here is an example where I used a square image:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 background:pink;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  background:  
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) left/calc((100vw - 100vh)/2) 100%  no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) right/calc((100vw - 100vh)/2) 100%  no-repeat,
   
   url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png) center center/auto 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Another example with another setting of the same image:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 background:pink;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  background:  
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) top/ 100% calc((100vh - 158px)/2)  no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom/ 100% calc((100vh - 158px)/2)  no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) left/calc((100vw - 158px)/2) 100%  no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) right/calc((100vw - 158px)/2) 100%  no-repeat,
   
  url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```